# Change sender ip in server

Tags: api, curl, proxy, http-proxy, whm

I need to make a lot of requests to a specific api through my server. But that api has limitations for each request, each route has weight, so each request must be sent from a different ip. Can anyone advise how to do this? Something like a proxy changer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this really works, but did u try adding "X-Forwarded-For" HTTP header ?